# OpenCV C++ simple object tracking

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I am completely new to OpenCV, OpenFrameworks, etc. My task is to trace a simple object (a drawing of a circle or a color bottlecap) and display a marker of any kind over the object in the video. I have searched very long and looked through many sites but there is no concise tutorial for a complete beginner, how to build, how to run, what to write and how to configure. Could someone please help me? I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For setup opencv in eclipse refer this link:
  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html.
- And for object detection first you need to train data for what you want to detect.For that refer these links,
  http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html#gsc.tab=0
  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html
  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier
- Hope this will help.